# Writing logs to Logstash directly or better through filebeat (Application performance perspective)?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, log4j2, filebeat

I'm doing a trade off between making my applications pushing directly to `Logstash` VS through `Filebeat` ?

I'm talking about the application performance & the emergencies perspectives ?

I know that `Filebeas` one of its options is the logstash loadbalancing by accepting multiple nodes in its configurations , on the opposite side pushing the logs directly to logstash from the application and using a proxy server in order to route internally between the logstash nodes.

So I need you recommendation for the long term solution with heavy pushes

Comment: what do you mean by `pushing the logs directly to logstash`?

Comment: I mean configuring `log4j2` in my application by using Gelf plugin for writing the logs directly to logstash

Comment: have you tried that? the reason I say because `logstash` reads data from other sources.

Comment: I did using Gref Plugin

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at [Logging in the Cloud](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html#Logging_using_ElasticSearch.2C_Logstash.2C_and_Kibana), which specifically discusses logging using ELK. Although your application may not be running in a cloud environment it is always a good idea to develop as if it will be.

Comment: that mean better to write directly from Application -> Logstash without Filebeat in mid , correct ?